# Run a video file with Java ( not in JPanel )

Tags: java, video

I searched for this and I coudn't find it anywhere. So basically what I want is when the user clicks an menu item, I want to launch a code that will automatically run a video file.. Is it possible?

If so how?

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: What do you mean by "not in JPanel?" Seems like a bit of an odd request. Do you mean you don't want to use swing and just awt? Or something else?

Comment: He means using OS shell association mime-type detection to launch a file based on its extension type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 6 you can open any file with the associated application

[Here is an article about it at oracle.](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to use the [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) Java Class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Java Media Frameword (JMF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html). See also the [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/). You need class MediaPlayer. It extends `java.awt.Component`, so you can use it in AWT environment, no need in Swing.